# CI / extending Controller / works locally but not on server

Tags: codeigniter, inheritance

I've got the following situation:

```
class User extends MY_Controller {
   (...)
}


class Game extends User {
   (...)
}
```

where class Game handles userinteractions / ajax requests etc. and class User is rather for sessions, db interactions etc. (within the class Game I'm refering to some methods of parent Controller). 
Everything works fine, if I'm working locally. But with the same constellation in server environment I don't get any responses from class Game. (I'm autloading the class in config - and the class itself seems to be found). But response is always empty. On the other hand I also don't get any errors at all... and so I'm asking myself what the problem might be?

Any settings I've forgotten?
Or am I on a complete wrong track at all and I can't just simply extend any Controller?

(sorry I'm quite new to CI)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need more info... like code, error messages, what have you tried, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically in CodeIgniter you have a separate controller for each. So, you have a `Users` controller and a `Game` controller.

When you need to do something with the users, you call a URL like `http://example.com/index.php/users/some_user_action` and same goes for the game (`http://example.com/index.php/game/some_game_action`).

The controllers might look like

```
// codeigniter/application/controllers/users.php
class Users extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        echo "I'm the index page and can be reached at http://example.com/index.php/users";
    }

    function some_user_action(){
        echo "I'm some user action; see me at http://example.com/index.php/users/some_user_action";
    }
}


// codeigniter/application/controllers/game.php
class Game extends CI_Controller{

    function index(){
        echo "I'm the Game controller index page and can be reached at http://example.com/index.php/game";
    }

    function some_game_action(){
        echo "I'm some game action; see me at http://example.com/index.php/game/some_user_action";
    }
}
```

CodeIgniter has great documentation; it's worth looking through. The intro tutorial is a good place to start: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html Also see the controllers page: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I know I can solve it this way - but I'm wondering why I can't extend the Controller class User... or actually I CAN and it IS working - but only in local environment and not on the server and I have no idea why it's not working there.

Comment: If it's not the right way to do it, why does it matter if it works on the server or not? At any rate, it could be any number of things causing the issue; would need more info (logs).

Comment: That's my problem I don't know if it is the wrong way, if it is always the wrong way doing it like that (?) :) or if it might work and anything else is wrong? But for now I will change it, so it's working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, that is always the wrong way (according to CI convention).  You can extend core controllers (see the user guide). Please accept this answer if it helped.